# Replace html tags using a regular expression - no script

Tags: html, regex, tags

I've been searching for a solution for hours, but haven't found any examples that help.

I want to search a plain text file and remove all instances of `<a id="pageXXX"></a>` where XXX is the page number.

I have tried

```
(^<a id="page)(.*:?)("></a>)

(^<a id=\\"page)(.*:?)(\\"></a>)

(^<a id="page)([0-9]+)("></a>)

(^<a id=\\"page)([0-9]+)(\\"></a>)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Not if you mean that HTML files cannot be searched with a regex.

Comment: They can, of course. But should they?

Comment: Should C#, PHP, Java, etc. files be searched? Seems there is a higher potential for disaster running a regex on those.

Answer (score 0):

This works correctly.

```
(<a id=\"page)(.*:?)(\"></a>)
```